# Heaps of marbles

Tags: mathematics, strategy, game, nim

Alice and Bob play the following game with two heaps of 10,000 and 20,000 marbles.

- Alice and Bob move alternatingly. Alice makes the first move.
- In every move, the active player may
  (i) either remove  ≥ 1 marbles from the first heap,
  (ii) or remove  ≥ 1 marbles from the second heap,
  (iii) or remove  ≥ 1 marbles from the first heap and  ≥ 1 marbles from the second heap, where  +  is divisible by 2016.
- The player who takes the *last* marble wins the game.

> **Question:** Which player is going to win this game?
> (As usual, we assume that Alice and Bob both use optimal strategies.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Alice wins

This is how:

> Alice first takes $9.112$ marbles from the first heap and $19.112$ from the second heap ($9.112 + 19.112 = 28.224 = 2.016 * 14$), leaving 888 marbles on each heap. From that on she just mirrors Bob's move keeping the heaps equal sized, making it impossible for Bob to win.

Comment: Seems too easy.  I wonder if this was close to the intended solution.

Comment: @Trenin The game is a variation on a game originally  proposed by Martin Gardner, where you could not take marbles from **both** heaps in the same move. This solution is the same, except it makes sure that Bob cannot again de-symmetrize the configuration by taking marbles from both piles simutaneously. Basically, Ivo's solution is to make the problem identical Martin Gardner's, where Alice always wins.